# SQL Server doesn't use missing indexes after it creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I ran into a very strange situation. I have a query and the optimizer advises to create an missing index for one of the tables. For example

```
create index on table1 (id) include (dt);
```

After the index is created, the optimizer doesn't use it, but advise to create the same index!
Never experienced this kind of behavior before. Can anyone suggest how to force SQL server to use the existing indexes?

Comment: It's likely using the cached plan.

Comment: or you created it in another database

Comment: Double check that the index is actually in the database you think it should be. Then if your query is still missing the index at (option recompile) at the end to force it to recompile.

Comment: Another thing to try is run your query manually but force the index with a query hint. Note - I'm not suggesting that this is the long-term fix, but may provide insight as to why the optimizer is not choosing that index organically.